# Get periods and words before and after (with overlapping matches)

Tags: regex

I want to get all periods plus surrounding words in some text. The text below can be an example:

> This study was aimed at designing production of isoeugenol and vanillin from eugenol of clove leaf oil and analyzing the potential product development financially. The specific objectives of this research work are: 1. Identify the isoeugenol and vanillin. 2. Model simulation of process design of isoeugenol and vanillin. 3. Study on financial feasibility and added value. This research is expected to provide maximum economic potential of eugenol to enhance the added value of clove leaf oil. The results showed that the FTIR and NMR products confirmed that isoeugenol and vanillin present in the synthesized product were identical to the reference standards.

When I use the pattern

```
\w+\.\s\w+
```

on the string above, it matches (from the section `and vanillin. 2. Model simulation`) `vanillin. 2` but it skips `2. Model`.

I want it to match both `vanillin. 2` and `2. Model`.

Can you give me some improvement so I get all periods?

Comment: Do you also want to match `standards.` at the end of the string?

Comment: I needn't it. Period in the end of string is easy to be identified.

Comment: OK, but it wouldn't hurt if the regex catches it too, then. Have you tried my solution?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. It doesn't work. Neither in regex tool I usually use. Do you have another solution?

Comment: The regex tool I linked to in my answer uses PHP, so it does work. Are you using it exactly like in my code sample? It's vital that you don't look at the match results themselves (which are always empty strings) but at the first capturing group's contents.

Comment: Yup, You are right. It is perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) together with a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
(?=(\b\w+\.(?:\s+\w+|$)))
```

Use it as follows:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=(\b\w+\.(?:\s+\w+|$)))/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[1];
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?=       # Assert that the following can be matched at the current position:
 (        # Capture into group number 1:
  \b      # - Beginning of a word
  \w+     # - an alphanumeric word
  \.      # - a dot
  (?:     # - Then either...
   \s+\w+ #   - whitespace and another word
  |       # - or... 
   $      #   - the end of the string.
  )       # End of alternation
 )        # End of capturing group 1
)         # End of lookahead
```

[See it in action on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/vW7eK1).